# Интервалы на строки для перебора

Tags: c#

Какие могут быть варианты, чтобы поставить пределы для перебора строк, не паролей, а простых строк, ну то есть чтобы было понятнее, первый поток идет от aaa до aae и второй поток идет от aaf до aak, потом первый поток снова выполняет от aal до aap, то есть чтобы потоки переберали много интервалов, независимо от того, какой интервал прописан.

Answer (score 3):

У вас, на самом деле, два вопроса: как сгенерировать последовательность строк и как её разбить на пачки, для обработки каждой в отдельном потоке.

Генерировать сразу всю последовательность целиком неэффективно, так как она будет занимать много памяти. Например, количество слов длиной по 6 символов, составленных из 26 различных букв (26<sup>6</sup>), составляет 308915776. И занимать в памяти такая коллекция будет свыше трёх гигабайт (по два байта на символ - юникод же).

Если подумать, то становится понятно, что данную последовательность строк можно представить в виде чисел в [n-ричной системе счисления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) по основанию, равному количеству символов. То есть, если использовать символы английского алфавита, получается 26-ричная система счисления.

Использовав [какой-либо алгоритм](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net) перевода чисел из одной системы счисления в другую, можно на лету получать нужные строки. В итоге не будет лишнего расхода памяти.

```
// Количество символов - основание системы счисления (26 букв в английском алфавите)
const int symbolCount = 26; // 'a...z'

// Длина слова
const int wordLength = 3; // 'aaa' - 'zzz'

// Набор символов (алфавит)
static char[] chars = Enumerable.Range('a', symbolCount).Select(n => (char)n).ToArray();

static string NumToString(int value)
{
    int index = wordLength;
    char[] buffer = new char[wordLength];

    do
    {
        buffer[--index] = chars[value % symbolCount];
        value = value / symbolCount;
    }
    while (value > 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        buffer[i] = 'a';

    return new string(buffer);
}
```

Для разбиения набора данных (последовательности строк) в дотнете можно использовать очень удобный метод [Partitioner.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd991564(v=vs.110).aspx). Он выдаёт кортежи с диапазонами индексов. Далее распараллеливаем вычисления, используя PLINQ.

Использование:

```
int wordCount = (int)Math.Pow(symbolCount, wordLength);

Partitioner.Create(0, wordCount).AsParallel().ForAll(range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        string str = NumToString(i);
        // здесь обработка str
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

я бы использовал функцию, обращение к которой выполняется потоками в рамках блока синхронизации lock () {}. Сама функция просто выдает очередную порцию строк, либо генерирует их, либо блоками считывая из внешнего источника.

Пример:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace threads
{
    class StringGenerator
    {
        private const int countStr = 10;
        private string currentString = "aa";
        public const string constEndOfList = "<end-of-list>"; // Ключевое слово, означающее завершение списка слов
        public List<string> getStrings()
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            for (int i=0; i<countStr; i++ )
            {
                if (!getNextString(currentString.Length - 1)) // все проверки опускаем для простоты
                {
                    result.Add(constEndOfList);
                }
                result.Add(currentString); 
            }
            return result;
        }
        private bool getNextString(int pos)
        {
            if (pos<0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            char posChar = currentString[pos];
            if (posChar == 'z')
            {
                bool hasNext = getNextString(pos - 1);
                if (hasNext)
                    ReplaceCharInString(ref currentString, pos, 'a');
                return hasNext;
            }
            else
            {
                ReplaceCharInString(ref currentString, pos, Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt16(posChar)+1) );
                return true;
            }
        }
        private void ReplaceCharInString(ref String str, int index, Char newSymb)
        {
            str = str.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, newSymb.ToString());
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static StringGenerator strGen = new StringGenerator();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            for (int t=0; t<10; t++)
                Task.Factory.StartNew(StringProcessor);

            Task.WaitAll();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void StringProcessor()
        {
            List<string> strList;
            bool hasStringsToProcess = true;
            do
            {
                lock (strGen)
                {
                    strList = strGen.getStrings();
                }
                foreach (string str in strList)
                {
                    if (str == StringGenerator.constEndOfList)
                    {                        
                        hasStringsToProcess = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} processing string {1}", Task.CurrentId, str));
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // типа идет обработка строки
                }
            } while (hasStringsToProcess);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task {0} terminated", Task.CurrentId));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то не очень похоже на правду... Ну, либо, неясно написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy "не очень похоже на правду" -что именно ?

Comment: прописать кол-ство знаков и интервал в каждом потоке

Comment: я описал словами общую идею, если автору вопроса нужен пример кода, думаю он уточнил бы

Comment: @Argon можете написать не большой пример, я примерно понимаю что вы написали, но не до конца ясно

Comment: Непохоже генерация строк в блоках lock - так от потоков польза сомнительна. В lock надо границы только генерировать, да и то, можно сначала снаружи сгенерировать границы, а потом уже потокам их скормить.

Comment: " В lock надо границы только генерировать" - это конечно будет оптимальнее. Я понял, что интересует сам механизм разделения строк между процессами.