# Алгоритм перебора всех возможных строк с заданным алфавитом не больше заданной длины

Tags: c++

Никак не получается придумать алгоритм, который бы генерировал все возможные строки с использованием заданного алфавита, с последовательным увеличением ее размера.
Алфавит например такой:

```
const string s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Нужно, чтобы алгоритм генерировал все возможные строки начиная с длины 1 до заданной.

Вообще изначально задание выглядит так: Пароль- это строка, состоящая из символов латинских букв и цифр ("1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM").

В некоторой системе при передаче паролей используются их ключевые значения, которые рассчитываются как:

```
int GetCode(string St)
{
    int N = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < St.Length; i++)
    {
        int C = (int)St[i];
        N = N * 10 + C * C;
    }
    return N ;
}
```

Требуется восстановить пароль по его ключевому значению. Ключевое значение берется из таблицы в соответствие с вашим вариантом. Программа должна реализовывать следующие требования:

Программа должна последовательно генерировать все возможные пароли, пока не найдет тот для которого значение ключа будет совпадать с заданным. Длина пароля должна последовательно возрастать.

Предусмотреть возможность параллельной генерации паролей.

Получить все пароли, для которых значение ключа совпадает с заданным.

Вариант: 122294884

Comment: Как минимум надо указать, - с повторяющимися буквами или без таковых...

Comment: Кстати, вы точно хотите сгенерировать все 85544256455804584088478900391073057799456650549471376572285576695009197049757337215044 строки? это все же малость побольше, чем оцениваемое количество атомов во вселенной...

Comment: Строка должна состоять из этих символов, они могут повторяться, но до ЗАДАННОЙ длины!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570675/184217

Comment: Самый простой алгоритм - генерируете все возможные сочетания длины k, сортируете и применяете алгоритм перестановок.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы алгоритм умел генерировать строки с длинной хотя бы до 5 элементов

Comment: См. обновленный ответ...

Answer (score 2):

А, впрочем, держите для неповторяющихся -

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename Bidirectional>
bool next_kpermutation( Bidirectional first, Bidirectional middle,
                        Bidirectional last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits< Bidirectional >::difference_type Int;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits< Bidirectional >::value_type      Val;

    if (middle == last)
    {
        return std::next_permutation(first,last);
    }

    if ( first == last )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Int n = std::distance(first, last);
    Int k = std::distance(first, middle);

    if ((k > n) || (k <= 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    Bidirectional i = last;

    for (Bidirectional j = middle; j-- != first; )
        if (std::max_element(j,last) != j)
        {
            i = j;
            break;
        }

    if (i == last)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Bidirectional j = i;
    ++j;

    while (!(*i < *j))
    {
        ++j;
    }

    Bidirectional imin = j;

    for (; j != last; ++j)
    {
        if ((*i < *j) && (*j < *imin))
        {
            imin = j;
        }
    }

    std::swap( *i, *imin );
    ++i;
    Bidirectional u = first;
    std::advance(u,std::min(k,n-1));

    while ( i != u )
    {
        Bidirectional i_min = i;
        for (Bidirectional i_k = i; ++i_k != last;)
        {
            if (*i_k < *i_min)
            {
                i_min = i_k;
            }
        }

        std::swap( *i, *i_min );
        ++i;
    }

    return true;
}


int main()
{
    string s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(int k = 1;;++k)
    {
        sort(s.begin(),s.end());
        do {
            cout << s.substr(0,k) << endl;
        } while(next_kpermutation(s.begin(),s.begin()+k,s.end()));
    }
}
```

Только даже 1,2,3 и 4 буквы - уже 13619044 строки выходит... Вам точно нужна именно эта постановка задачи? Что-то мне кажется, что у вас типичная XY-проблема...

С повторами еще проще - просто переписываем в код алгоритм с 330 страницы тома 4А "Искусства программирования":

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
void generate(unsigned int n)
{
    vector<int> a(n+1,0);
    for(;;)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
            cout << s[a[i]];
        cout << endl;

        int j;
        for(j = n; a[j] == (j ? 61 : 1); --j)
        {
            a[j] = 0;
        }
        if (j == 0) break;
        a[j]++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    for(int k = 1; ; ++k)
        generate(k);
}
```

Но не верю, что вам нужны все эти строки, не верю... Явно не то вам нужно **на самом деле**.

**Update**

Итак, очевидно, что ваш пароль может состоять только из 5 символов. Просто рассматривая в качестве первого `'0'` и `'z'` и алгоритм проверки.

Итого не более 62^5 = 916132832 варианта.

Не менее очевидно, что первый символ не может иметь код, больше 110. И не меньше 102...

Опять же, если подумать, то ясно, что последним может быть один из символов `"04DHNRXbflpvz"`. Эти соображения сокращают перебор почти в 33 раза - до 27884376 вариантов.

Которые - заведомо зная длину - проще всего считать 5 циклами. Можно существенно повысить скорость, вычисляя значение кода для одной строки из предыдущей, но это уже, как я понимаю, для некоторых высшая математика, не будем в нее лезть. Ограничимся сказанным и получим такую вот простенькую программку:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int GetCode(const string& St)
{
    int N = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < St.length(); i++)
    {
        int C = (int)St[i];
        N = N * 10 + C * C;
    }
    return N;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const string s = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    string test = "     ";
    for(char c = 102; c <= 110; ++c)
    {
        test[0] = c;
        for(auto c1: s)
        {
            test[1] = c1;
            for(auto c2: s)
            {
                test[2] = c2;
                for(auto c3: s)
                {
                    test[3] = c3;
                    for(auto c4: "04DHNRXbflpvz")
                    {
                        test[4] = c4;
                        if (GetCode(test) == 122294884)
                            cout << test << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы и подобранные куда менее чем за секунду пароли см. по адресу https://ideone.com/PNmT7t

Как я и говорил, вместо того, чтоб спросить, как забить гвоздь, изначально вы спрашивали, как правильно держать микроскоп для его забивания...

P.S. Если выбросить строки и переписать иначе - [вообще летает](https://ideone.com/KnvtRl)...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for(auto c : "fghijklmn" )
    {
        int code1 = c*c*10000;
        for(auto c1: s)
        {
            int code2 = code1 + c1*c1*1000;
            for(auto c2: s)
            {
                int code3 = code2 + c2*c2*100;
                for(auto c3: s)
                {
                    int code4 = code3 + c3*c3*10;
                    for(auto c4: "04DHNRXbflpvz")
                    {
                        int code = code4 + c4*c4;
                        if (code == 122294884)
                            cout << c << c1 << c2 << c3 << c4 << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```