# Генерация паролей

Tags: c#

Есть алфавит

```
string alphabet= "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Допустим мы хотим сгенерировать N паролей, размером 2 символа. Должно получиться

```
00, 01, 02, 03....... xz, yz, zz.
```

Как сделать такое?

Comment: Повторы допустимы? Каков порядок N - 1, 10, 1000, 1000000000 ?

Comment: непонятен принцип подбора пар

Comment: @Kromster ну N допустим 100 будет

Comment: Тогда все просто - выбираете рандомом 1 символ, 2 символ, проверяете что такой пары еще не было и сохраняете. В чем затруднения?

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570675/184217)

Answer (score 3):

Банальный перебор

```
string alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++)
        Console.WriteLine($"{alphabet[i]}{alphabet[j]}");
```

Вывод

```
00
01
02
03
04  
... 
ZT
ZU
ZV
ZW
ZX
ZY
ZZ
```

Comment: может все-таки `for (var j = 0`?

Comment: @trollingchar тогда они повторяться будут же

Comment: @trollingchar хотя вы правы, поправлю ответ

Comment: не будут, потому что порядок букв другой

Comment: да да, уже осознал, поправил )

Comment: вывод тоже будет в конце `ZX ZY ZZ`

Comment: @trollingchar готово