# C#: Перебор всех вариантов написания слова

Tags: c#

хотелось написать программу на c# для перебора всех вариантов написания слова. причём буквы в должны быть замещены не только этой же буквой в другом регистре, но и  спец символами или несколькими символами.
К примеру. Есть начальное слово password.
есть таблица возможных замен:

```
p->{p,P,|*}
a->{a,A,@,/-\}
s->{s,S,$}
w->{w,W,\/\/}
o->{o,O,0,()}
r->{r,R,/2}
d->{d,D,[)}
```

На выходе должно быть (3^6)*(4^2)=11664 варианта без повторов.
не могу для решения придумать алгоритм. Помогите советом пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570675/184217

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно, точнее я бы даже сказал совсем не то что нужно. здесь есть рабочий вариант https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permute-string-changing-case/ только для перебора вариантов в верхнем и нижнем регистре. но для перебора на основе табличных подстановок он не годится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишет в файл `D:\brute_force_result.txt` все возможные комбинации.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Recursion
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int Counter = 0;

        public static void BruteForce(string word, Dictionary<Char, string[]> substitute, StreamWriter sw, string result="")
        {
            if (word != string.Empty)
            {
                foreach (string symbol in substitute[word[0]])
                {
                    BruteForce(word.Substring(1), substitute, sw, result + symbol);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Counter++;
                sw.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "password";

            Dictionary<Char, string[]> substitute = new Dictionary<char, string[]>
            {
                { 'p', new string[] { "p", "P", "|*"} },
                { 'a', new string[] { "a", "A", "@", "/-\\" } },
                { 's', new string[] { "s", "S", "$" } },
                { 'w', new string[] { "w", "W", "\\/\\/" } },
                { 'o', new string[] { "o", "O", "0", "()" } },
                { 'r', new string[] { "r", "R", "/2" } },
                { 'd', new string[] { "d", "D", "[)" } }
            };

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(@"D:\brute_force_result.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)))
            {
                BruteForce(word, substitute, sw);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"DONE! [{Counter}]");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, век живи век учись. Спасибо за ответ.