# Получить числа составленные из 1, 2, 3, 4 по возрастанию

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Всем привет!
Мне нужно получить массив чисел которые состоят из 1, 2, 3, 4 и чтобы в массиве числа стояли по возрастанию.
Нужно получить до n-ого числа(1<=n<=10^9)
И это должно работать максимально быстро.

В массив возможно не поместится, попробуйте вектор из stl

Comment: Что значит "состоят из"? Представляют собой сумму этих цифр?

Comment: к примеру 1234 1342 12 32

Comment: Повторы разрешены? 1122?

Comment: да, можно......

Comment: arr[0] = 1111,  arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1

Comment: цыфра не объязательна должна состаять и 4 цыфер, я в примере указал что может быть 12 32

Comment: Еще - вам нужно просто их генерировать или по номеру получать число?

Comment: На первый взгляд, эти числа напоминают n-ричную систему счисления. Пример её использования: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570675/184217

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int v[9] = {1};
    for(;;)
    {
        int val = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) val = v[8-i] + val*10;
        cout << val << endl;
        int c = 1;
        for(int i = 0; c && i < 9; ++i)
        {
            v[i] += c;
            c = 0;
            if (v[i] > 4) v[i] = c = 1;
        }
        if (c) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `с` как шпенёк переноса в счётчике ;)

Comment: @MBo carry :) :)

Comment: можете объяснить код?

Comment: А что тут пояснять? Выполняю обычное сложение 1+1 = 2, 2+1 = 3, ..., 4+1 = 1 и перенос 1 в следующий разряд. Просто увеличение счетчика, в котором цифрами служат 1-4. Для вывода - собираю число из цифр.

Comment: а как получить тот массив который я хочу?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы я вводил какой то n и на выход получал массиы в котором есть первые n таких чисел

Comment: @E_d_u_a_r_d Вы серьёзно не можете сложить val в массив?

Comment: @MBo извините тупанул...